# Where should I put keys at my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, ruby-on-rails-5, web-push

I am trying to use the gem webpush to create push notifications at my rails app.

At [this part at tutorial](https://github.com/zaru/webpush#generating-vapid-keys) he say:

*"Use webpush to generate a VAPID key that has both a public_key and private_key attribute to be saved on the server side."*

```
# One-time, on the server
vapid_key = Webpush.generate_key

# Save these in your application server settings
vapid_key.public_key
vapid_key.private_key
```

My doubt is: What exactly is "application server settings"? Where should I put these keys at my rails app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idealy it should be stored in `environment variables` (depends on the OS you use).
If you are using `dotenv` gem and find it conveniant to use `dotenv` in production you can store it in `.env` file.
To use a variable use ENV['NAME']

Also for this purpose you can use default rails `config/secrets.yml` file. To use a variable use `Rails.application.secrets.name`.

Also you can combine env variables with secrets.yml file like:

## secrets.yml

```
...
 key: ENV['NAME']
```

benefit: use variable independent of rails environment.

Notice: Neve share you credentials file to git or any public repo! If you need to share this file with other developers just send them copy with development keys.

Links:

[dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)

[environment variables](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)

[secrets.yml](https://richonrails.com/articles/the-rails-4-1-secrets-yml-file)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a gem](https://github.com/Deekor/site_variables) to help with this now that Rails no longer supports `secrets.yml.`

REMINDER: you should never store a private key or any other secret variable in a file that is committed to your version control - use environment variables for that.